# How can I determine the type of the items that get added to a TabControl?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I've created a `CloseableTabItem` control that derives from `TabItem`.
Now I'd like to specify that a given `TabControl` should add new items using `CloseableTabItem` instead of `TabItem`.
Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class CloseableItemsTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new CloseableTabItem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to make your own `ClosableTabControl` that extends `TabControl` in order to override the base functionality.

However, you can also probably just add your tabs manually, feeding it your `ClosableTabItems` instead of regular `TabItems`.  It would be safe to assume this is possible since most collection-based controls are able to be programatically populated this way.

Comment: About the first option... how can I extend TabControl to fulfil my requirement?
About the second option... I don't own the code that populate the TabControl so I cannot do that. The things that are added to the TabControl are generally of UserControl type.